# Proof by Induction: for all integers n $\ge$ 0, $12\mid8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction, divisibility

I'm working on a homework problem for my discrete math class, and I'm stuck. (Note: I made a post about this earlier, but I read the problem incorrectly, thus the work was wrong, so I deleted the post.)

Prove by mathematical induction that for every integer n $\ge$ 0,  $12\mid8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2}$

I start out by proving the base case, $F(0)$, to be true:

$$
F(0)=8^1+2^2=12\quad \text{Obviously, 12 is divisible by 12}
$$

I then move on to the induction step to prove the $F(n+1)$ is true:

I assume that $8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2}$ is divisible by 12, and then plug in $(n+1)$:

$$
F(n+1)=8^{2(n+1)+1}+2^{4(n+1)+2}=8^{2n+3}+2^{4n+6}
$$

I then do $F(n+1)-F(n)$:

$$
F(n+1)-F(n)=(8^{2n+3}+2^{4n+6})-(8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2})
$$

$$
=8^{2n+3}-8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+6}-2^{4n+2}
$$

I then factor out the terms used in $F(n)$:

$$
8^{2n+1}(8^2-1)+2^{4n+2}(2^4-1)=8^{2n+1}(63)+2^{4n+2}(15)
$$

I can re-write the result as:

$$
8^{2n+1}(63)+2^{4n+2}(12+3)
$$

This is where I'm stuck. I broke up the $15$ into $12+3$ since I need to prove that there is a multiple of 12, but I don't know what to do with the 63, since (I think) you're supposed to have the terms in $F(n)$ multiplied by 3 after you distribute so that you can factor out the 3 and have $F(n)$ in the equation, which is proven to be divisible by 12.

I tried splitting the $63$ into $(21*3)$

$$
8^{2n+1}(21*3)+2^{4n+2}(12+3)
$$

But I'm not sure what to do next. Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be OK, each of $8^{2n+1}\times 63$ and $2^{4n+2}\times 15$ is obviously divisible by $12$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have $F(n)=12k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$
F(n+1)=8^{2(n+1)+1}+2^{4(n+1)+2}=8^{2n+3}+2^{4n+6}, 
$$
then
\begin{align}
8^{2n+3}+2^{4n+6}
&=64\cdot8^{2n+1}+16\cdot2^{4n+2}\\
&=12(5\cdot8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2})+4(8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2})\\
 &=12(5\cdot8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2}+4k),
\end{align}
which is divisible by 12.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you went from $64*8^{2n+1}+16*2^{4n+2}$ to $12(5*8^{2n+1}+2^{4n+2})+4F(n)$ Could you explain?

Comment: @Travis See my a bit simplified answer (plus observation, that $64=12\cdot5+4$, $16=12+4$).

Comment: You're allowed to just move the $4F(n)$ inside the parentheses? I see what you did with $64=12*5+4, 16=12+4$ (which is really clever, btw), but I don't understand how you put $4F(n)$ inside the parentheses.

Comment: @Travis Ops! You are right. Corrected.

Comment: Adding the fact that $F(n)=12k$ turned on a light bulb. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$$
8^{2n+1}\cdot63+2^{4n+2}\cdot 15=8^{2n}\cdot(8\cdot63)+2^{4n}\cdot(4\cdot15).
$$